# removing line breaks in a csv file

Tags: python, regex, csv, line-breaks

I have a csv file with lines, each line begins with (@) and all the fields within a line are separated with (;). One of the fields, that contains "Text" (""[ ]""), has some line breaks that produce errors while importing the whole csv file to excel or access. The text after the line breaks is considered as independent lines, not following the structure of the table.

```
@4627289301; Lima, Peru; 490; 835551022915420161; Sat Feb 25 18:04:22 +0000 2017; ""[OJO!
la premiacin de los #Oscar, nuestros amigos de @cinencuentro revisan las categoras.
+info: co/plHcfSIfn8]""; 0
@624974422; None; 114; 835551038581137416; Sat Feb 25 18:04:26 +0000 2017; ""[Porque nunca dejamos de amar]""; 0
```

any help with this using a python script? or any other solution...

as output I would like to have the lines:

```
@4627289301; Lima, Peru; 490; 835551022915420161; Sat Feb 25 18:04:22 +0000 2017; ""[OJO! la premiacin de los #Oscar, nuestros amigos de @cinencuentro revisan las categoras. +info: co/plHcfSIfn8]""; 0
@624974422; None; 114; 835551038581137416; Sat Feb 25 18:04:26 +0000 2017; ""[Porque nunca dejamos de amar]""; 0
```

any help? I a csv file (54MB) with a lot of lines with line breaks... some other lines are ok...

Comment: and also, the @ inside the comment is no to be considered is it?

Comment: I would like to get all the lines structured as the second line of the example (@624914422...)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Seems like there is fairly simple way to start off. Read it line by line and discard the `@` and split by `;` or else use the csv module.

Comment: The duplicated double quotes look like exactly the wrong thing.  Some dialects of CSV allow for newlines inside quoted strings but they should be wrapped with a single double quote character on each side, not two.

Answer (score 0):

You should share your expected output as well.

Anyways, I suggest you first clean your file to remove the newline characters. Then you can read it as csv. One solution can be (I believe someone will suggest something better :-) )

**Clean the file (on linux):**

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' input_file | sed "s/ @/\n@/g" > output_file
```

**Read file as csv** (You can read it using any other method)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('output_file', delimiter=';', header=None)
df.to_csv('your_csv_file_name', index=False)
```

Let's see if it helps you :-)

Comment: Thanks @PaulRooney

Answer (score 0):

You can search for lines that are followed by a line that doesn't start with "@", like this `\r?\n+(?!@\d+;)`.

The following was generated from this regex101 [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gEIbnS/3). It replaces such line ends with a space. You can change that to whatever you like.

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"\r?\n+(?!@\d+;)"

test_str = ("@4627289301; Lima, Peru; 490; 835551022915420161; Sat Feb 25 18:04:22 +0000 2017; \"\"[OJO!\n"
    "la premiacin de los #Oscar, nuestros amigos de @cinencuentro revisan las categoras.\n"
    "+info: co/plHcfSIfn8]\"\"; 0\n"
    "@624974422; None; 114; 835551038581137416; Sat Feb 25 18:04:26 +0000 2017; \"\"[Porque nunca dejamos de amar]\"\"; 0")

subst = " "

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: It doesn´t work, the demo add some characters to the real text line when creating the code...

Comment: @luisec I don't understand what that means? If it just means it's adding a space, that's because of `subst = " "`, you can change that to "", or whatever you might like to replace it with

Comment: In the first line after the text "OJO!" the demo adds "\n" when exporting the code with the example (from the demo, I already tried it)... the original line does not have these characters to identify where the line breaks are...

Comment: @luisec `\n` just means newline in string objects. It's only present in the sample. Many languages support this. If you look at the demo @ https://regex101.com/r/gEIbnS/3 you'll see the sample text has no literal `\n`.  This is just how regex101 generated sample code.